# Why has gpu stopped working for me in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am a university professor trying to learn deep learning for a possible class in the future. I have been using google colab with GPU support for the past couple of months. Just recently, the GPU device is not found. But, I am doing everything that I have done in the past. I can't imagine that I have done anything wrong because I am just working through tutorials from books and the tensorflow 2.0 tutorials site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58962312/edit) to include more specifics about your situation; include the exact error message you're getting, as well as the steps you had been previously taking to perform your work. Please put those details as *text directly in the question*. This will make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

tensorflow 2 on Colab GPU was broken recently due to an upgrade from CUDA 10.0 to CUDA 10.1. As of this afternoon, the issue should be resolved for the tensorflow builds bundled with Colab. That is, if you run the following magic command:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

then `import tensorflow` will import a working, GPU-compatible tensorflow 2.0 version.

Note, however, if you attempt to install a version of tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow-gpu` or similar, the result may not work in Colab due to system incompatibilities.

See https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb for more information.